# How can a Google apps administrator impersonate another user to get other's gmail?

Tags: api, gmail

I am writing a script to access all Google apps domain users emails by using IMAP and Google OAuth. This script should let me delete, move and export any users emails.  However, I cannot find any clue in Google API to impersonate another user to access his email. (This impersonation is easy for Google Docs, but not available for  Gmail. )     Please help,  any suggestion is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: solved by 2 legged Oauth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2Legged OAuth 1.0 can solve this problem.  I don't know when Google will publish 2 legged Oauth 2.0 to Gmail and other API services, but I am looking forward to it.